# How to fix AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

When doing `sudo apachectl graceful` on my Debian 9 server I got the "AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded." error message. The webserver still started and the error log was empty.

However I would like to get rid of the error message.

What did I do to get this error? I disabled the "mpm event" module with `sudo a2dismod mpm_event`.

See my answer below on how to mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When disabling the "mpm event" module I fogot to enable the module meant to replace it for my purpose. Thus to mitigate I had to enable the "php module" with `sudo a2enmod php7.0`. In this case the "php module" was called "php7.0" since this is the version shipped with Debian 9. For Debian 10 this will be `sudo a2enmod php7.3`.

Alternatively one cold re-enable the "mpm event" module with `sudo a2enmod mpm_event`.

Comment: This causes the actual MPM, the ancient low performance `mpm_prefork`, to be enabled, as it is the only MPM which will run mod_php.

Comment: This is indeed true.